# kdb/q: How to apply a string manipulation function to a vector of strings to output a vector of strings?

Tags: string, function, vectorization, kdb

Thanks in advance for the help.  I am new to kdb/q, coming from a Python and C++ background.
Just a simple syntax question: I have a string with fields and their corresponding values

```
pp_str: "field_1:abc field_2:xyz field_3:kdb"
```

I wrote an atomic (scalar) function to extract the value of a given field.

```
get_field_value: {[field; pp_str] pp_fields: " " vs pp_str; pid_field:  pp_fields[where like[pp_fields; field,":*"]]; start_i: (pid_field[0] ss ":")[0] + 1; end_i: count pid_field[0]; indices: start_i + til (end_i - start_i); pid_field[0][indices]}

show get_field_value["field_1"; pp_str]
"abc"

show get_field_value["field_3"; pp_str]
"kdb"
```

Now how do I generalize this so that if I input a vector of fields, I get a vector of values?  I want to input ("field_1"; "field_2"; "field_3") and output ("abc"; "xyz"; "kdb").  I tried multiple approaches (below) but I just don't understand kdb/q's syntax well enough to vectorize my function:

```
/ Attempt 1 - Fail
get_field_value[enlist ("field_1"; "field_2"); pp_str]

/ Attempt 2 - Fail
get_field_value[; pp_str] /. enlist ("field_1"; "field_3")

/ Attempt 3 - Fail
fields: ("field_1"; "field_2")
get_field_value[fields; pp_str]
```

Answer (score 1):

To run your function for each you could project the pp_str variable and use `each` for the others

```
q)get_field_value[;pp_str]each("field_1";"field_3")
"abc"
"kdb"
```

Kdb actually has built-in functionality to handle this: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/file-text/#key-value-pairs

```
q){@[;x](!/)"S: "0:y}[`field_1;pp_str]
"abc"
q)
q){@[;x](!/)"S: "0:y}[`field_1`field_3;pp_str]
"abc"
"kdb"
```

Comment: Follow-up question: But now how do I do this for each line in my text file (each of the 3 strings in "q4")? In Python or C++ logic, basically I want to do a nested for-loop, the outer loop to iterate through each of the strings, and then within that, for each string, the inner loop grabs the value for each of the keys (fields):

/ Attempt 1 - Fail
get_field_value[each fields ; each q4]

/ Attempt 2 - Fail
each[get_field_value[; each q4]] fields

/ Attempt 3 - Fail
get_field_value[; each q4] each fields
How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: The general approach is to make the `pp_str` a variable, say `x`, and then wrap it in a lambda and apply to each string. Something like ```{{@[;x](!/)"S: "0:y}[`field_1`field_3;x]}each q4```. This is assuming you want to extract the same fields for each string

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the syntax you're looking for.

```
q)get_field_value[; pp_str]each("field_1";"field_2")
"abc"
"xyz"
```